# Should the namespace (and action) start with a slash?

Tags: java, rest, struts2, struts2-rest-plugin

We are developing an Struts 2 base web application.

Please let me know which is correct (standard) in Strust 2 application

```
<s:url var="url" action="foo" namespace="bar" />
<s:url var="url" action="/foo" namespace="/bar" />
<s:url var="url" action="foo" namespace="/bar" />
```

**Long story:**

To get an action url we always used below

```
<s:url var="url" action="foo" namespace="bar" />
```

We tried to add the rest support to our application and make our application support rest and non rest actions same as mentioned in [REST and non-RESTful URL's Together Configuration](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/rest/#rest-and-non-restful-urls-together-configuration)

and also [Struts2 REST and Non-REST action together](https://github.com/sivailango/struts2-rest-nonrest).

It seems that the `<s:url var="url" action="foo" namespace="bar" />` is always mapped to default action, while the `<s:url var="url" action="/foo" namespace="/bar" />` works fine.

Is it a bug in `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.PrefixBasedActionMapper` class or the action and namespace should always have slashes?

Comment: Namespace with, action without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the line

> [**REST and non-RESTful URL's Together Configuration**](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/rest/#rest-and-non-restful-urls-together-configuration)
>
> And, again, we're relying on the Convention plugin to find our
> controllers, so we need to configure the convention plugin a bit:
>
> ```
> <constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Controller"/>
> <constant name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches" value="true"/>
> <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="rest-default"/>
> <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="example"/>
> ```

says that you should use Convention plugin, that means convention based action mapper. This mapper *allows* the action name with a leading slash. You are using Struts for years and should know that default action mapper doesn't.

The `s:url` tag doesn't define any namespace or action in the configuration, it's using `UrlHelper` to generate url based on its own logic. What is generated is used to access the action mapper. Normally URLs are generated with

```
 http://<host>:<port>/<context>/<namespace>/<action>[.<extension>]
```

If you print the url generated from the tags you'll see which is correct one. We are using namespace with a leading slash and action name without slash in the action attribute. These values should correspond to the configuration settings.